# Camel timer reset after suspend

Tags: timer, apache-camel

I want camel timer to be reset every time the route it is in, is resumed.

The problem is I use timer to manage sending logon messages with long interval and it works fine the first time but after reconnection and resuming of logon route it seems that timer remembers the state in which it was prior to suspension.

Maybe it is expected behaviour in most cases but in mine I could use some way to change it. From what I know now I could achieve that by stopping and starting the route, but maybe there is some other way ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible the same question posted alreadt on the Camel mailing list where its being discussed and answered: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Timer-with-delay-0-and-repeatCount-1-does-not-fire-after-resumed-td5737036.html